# Sendmail/procmail - get mail sender and mail subject, utf8 encoding issues

Tags: linux, character-encoding, debian, postfix-mta, procmail

My .procmailrc (really simple):

```
:0c
| $HOME/send_sms.sh "`formail -xFrom:`" "`formail -xSubject:`"
```

So, sender named "mail@domain.com" sends message with subject "Subject test ąść". The script "send_sms.sh" receives:

Sender:  `=?UTF-8?Q?mail@domain.com?= <mail@domain.com>`

Subject: `=?UTF-8?Q?Subject_test_=C4=85=C5=9B=C4=87?=`

How should I modify my .procmailrc to get clear text? Or convert this in my script send_sms.sh ?

Comment: I recommend you ask this on http://unix.stackexchance.com.

Comment: What should it convert "Erdnüße" into?  What about "Россия" or "مصر" or "日本"?

Comment: Ok, maybe I was not clear. This is encoded part of mail header (int this example, utf8, but it also could be base64 or quoted-printable etc). And I need to decode this to readable form (like email clients do). Is this possible with bash, or maybe with formail itself?

Comment: UTF-8 is a character set, base64 and QP are encodings.  Your examples have a character set of UTF-8 and an quoted-printable encoding.  They could have any other character set as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[http://metacpan.org/pod/Email::MIME::RFC2047::Decoder](http://metacpan.org/pod/Email%3a%3aMIME%3a%3aRFC2047%3a%3aDecoder) has a simple RFC2047 decoder in Perl.  You should perhaps only decode strings which are in a character set you can support, but all your examples are in UTF-8, so if your script supports sending UTF-8 in SMS, you should be fine.  For other character sets, perhaps you can convert into UTF-8 in a separate step before sending.